# Problem with 2nd part of exercise on symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

> Let $M$ be a symmetric matrix (ie $M = M^T$) of the dimension $n \times n$, and a $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be a standard scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that
>
> ($1$) $\langle u,Mv \rangle$ = $\langle Mu, v\rangle$
>
> ($2$)Deduce from this that if $\lambda \neq \lambda^{\prime}$ are the different eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $M$ with the eigenvectors $v$ and $v^{\prime}$, $\langle v, v^{\prime}\rangle=0$, $v$ and $v^{\prime}$ are perpendicular.

I know how to show (1) but I do not have idea how from this deduce (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $Mv=\lambda v$ and $Mw=\mu w$ with $\lambda\neq \mu$. Then
$$ \lambda\langle v,w\rangle=\langle Mv,w\rangle=\langle v,Mw\rangle=\mu\langle v,w\rangle$$
which implies that
$$ (\lambda-\mu)\langle v,w\rangle=0$$
Since $\lambda\neq \mu$, this means that $\langle v,w\rangle=0$, i.e. $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal.

Comment: could u tell me how we know that $\lambda-\mu)\langle v,w\rangle=0$

Comment: The first line shows that $\lambda\langle v,w\rangle=\mu\langle v,w\rangle$. Now subtract the RHS from both sides.

Comment: Oh sorry that was obvious but i have 1 more question we know that  $(\lambda-\mu) \neq 0 $ but i dont know why this is $\langle v,w\rangle$ give us 0 i know we use that $\sum_{i=1}^n u_{i}w_{i}$

Comment: The product of the real numbers $\lambda-\mu$ and $\langle v,w\rangle$ is zero. The first real number $\lambda-\mu$ is known to be non-zero. This means that the second real number $\langle v,w\rangle$ is zero.

Comment: But how we know that $\langle v,w\rangle=0$ Ok i get it why is  that. My bad. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: $Mv=\lambda v$ how we know this, that is any fact? where can i find it?

Comment: That's what it means for $v$ to be an eigenvector for $M$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\langle Mv, v'\rangle = \lambda \langle v,v'\rangle$ on the one hand and $\langle v, Mv'\rangle = \lambda'\langle v,v'\rangle$ on the other. Now since the two things are equal by part (1),$(\lambda-\lambda')\langle v,v'\rangle =0 $, and since $\lambda\neq\lambda'$, $\langle v,v'\rangle =0$.

Comment: could u tell me how we know that $(\lambda-\mu)\langle v,v'\rangle=0$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming part (1):

In (1), choose $u = v'$ to get
$$
\left< v',Mv \right> = \left< v',\lambda v \right> = \lambda \left< v', v \right>
\\ \left< Mv',v \right> = \left< \lambda' v', v \right> = \lambda' \left< v', v \right>\\
\lambda \left< v', v \right>=  \lambda' \left< v', v \right> \\
(\lambda-\lambda') \left< v', v \right>= 0
$$
and since $\lambda-\lambda' \neq 0$,$$ \left< v', v \right>= 0$$

Comment: could u tell me how we know that $(\lambda-\mu)\langle v,v'\rangle=0$